# Google Play Console: the meaning of "Active Users"

Tags: android, google-play-console

The 'Active Users' on Google Play Console is defined as: "*The number of users who have your app installed on at least one device **that was active** in the preceding 30 days*".

Is the phrase "***that was active***" refer to the app usage or just the device activity?

In other word, can I use this metric to measure if the users are using/opening my app? or it is just an indication on how many active devices have my app installed but not necessarily using it.

If this definition doesn't help in indicating how many time the app was used, how can I measure that?

Below is a screenshot of the Active User reporting UI, where we can find the definition of "Active Users":

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means how many active devices have your app installed but **not necessarily using it**. If you want to find out how many people are using it daily, you have to implement analytics. Here is a guide on how to do it: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification, do you know if there is a way to know how many times the app was used? or how many users used the app?

Comment: @Rami use analytics

Comment: This might help you! https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-find-the-number-of-active-users-of-an-app

Comment: if any install is done then count is updated in play console. what if any uninstall is done, then also count is updated in playconsole?

Comment: Yes, the count is going to lower if user removes app from his device.

Answer (score 3):

The active users states that number of users currently installed your app on their device.It means the count is not based on the app uses. As stated [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) , The number of users who have your app installed on at least one device and have used the device in the past 30 days. **So it doesnt mean the users have used your app**.

And if you want to **Realtime active users count** you can make it by use of firebase analytics [documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317517#active-users).

Hope it helps!